# Regex for Not allow all same characters even included single special character

Tags: java, regex

Requirement :

Trying to create the regex for the below conditions, I have tried the one regex it's working as expected other than one condition as it does not allow duplicates even separated by particular Char &.

1. Allow Alpha Numeric characters with a minimum of 12 and a maximum of 14
2. No special characters are allowed other than & ( only one)
3. Not Allow all the same characters even separated by &
4. Length is same between 12 to 14 even including the &

ex:

```
111111111111 not allowed as all are the same characters
1111111&11111 not allowed as all are the same characters even & is there
111111111112 allowed 
1111111&11112 allowed
ABC123567GHDG4 allowed
```

```
^(\d)(?!\1+$)(?=.{11,13}$)[0-9]*(?:[&][0-9]+)?$
```

The above regex is working other than the case `1111111&11111`

Comment: You may try this regex: `^(?!&?(\d)(?:&?\1)+$)(?=.{12,14}$)\d*(?:&\d*)?$`

Comment: Thanks anubhava  the above regex working as expected but its allowed only Numerics but it need to allow the Alphabets as well.

And & is not allowed Begining and ending of the text.
Like 11122344111& and &11122344111 not allowed

Answer (score 1):

You may use this regex for your conditions:

```bash
^(?!([\da-zA-Z])(?:&?\1)+$)(?=.{12,14}$)[\da-zA-Z]+(?:&[\da-zA-Z]+)?$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/o0Ydy8/1)

**RegEx Details:**

- `^`: Start
- `(?!([\da-zA-Z])(?:&?\1)+$)`: Negative lookahead to assert failure when same digit or letter is repeated till end
- `(?=.{12,14}$)`: Positive lookahead to make sure there are 12 to 14 characters
- `[\da-zA-Z]+`: Match 1+ digits or letters
- `(?:&[\da-zA-Z]+)?`: Optionally match `&` followed by 1+ of digits or letters
- `$`: End

Comment: I have a feeling that SO is becoming less popular.

Comment: true, ChatGPT effect I believe!